# CLLocationManager starts update before user authorization Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Having some issues using location manager.
It seems like locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuth does not stop app flow, and startUpdatingLocation is called before user can dismiss auth alert.
How to avoid this?

My app loads default values for non-available GPS, so I always get default (because this func is called even if "want to auth this app...?" alert is still showing).

My code:

```
if ask{
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.manageLocation()
    }

func manageLocation(){
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()) {

        case .notDetermined, .restricted, .denied:
            // load default deck
            self.loadBlink(useDefault: true)

        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.distanceFilter = 10.0
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }
    } else {
        // load default deck
        self.loadBlink(useDefault: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your put a code for location access authentication and startUpdatingLocation in app delegates ?

Comment: Location manager will start updating location if you have already granted permission before.

Comment: Nope, should I? @HimanshuMoradiya

Comment: Yes, but it does not wait! @Dev_Tandel

Comment: location manager will start updating location if you have granted permission. Once you gave permission why you want to wait?

Comment: if you want to wait for user input every time then start your location manager services on alert action

Comment: Look at my code, manageLocation() is called before user accept auth @Dev_Tandel

Comment: delete app, install it again, Do not perform any action, Goto to device setting and see what permission is there for location services.

Comment: Yes @GiuseppeCapoluongo you have to put code in appdelagates and if you want then i will upload it

Answer (score 0):

Requesting authorization in asynchronous. It returns immediately, and you have to take that into account.

Comment: Excuse me, what does this mean? @Andreas

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation Means you get a callback when the user is done answering the question. You don't block the thread just to wait for the user.

Answer (score -1):

Add this into your **info.plist**

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your location.</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) would like to use your location.</string>
```

set `var locationManager`:

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
```

on `viewDidLoad` call this:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init]; // objective-c
locationManager = CLLocationManager() // swift (if i'm not wrong)
```

call this `requestWhenInUseAuth` before you call `startUpdatingLocation`

Comment: I did, still nothing @Hezron

Comment: to make sure it works, you should reinstall your app

Comment: Location services are already working..please go through the question once